# bower-auto-link npm module will find the components outside working directory

Tags: node.js

Is the below module, works when my projects structure as below.
https://github.com/anandanand84/bower-auto-link

Different project structure.,

```
/component-project-1
/component-project-2
/webproject
  /app/bower_components/
```

There are 3 projects above, will the npm moduler "bower-auto-link" identifies component projects? when I install it in the webproject?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Yes it does.

lets say you have

```
projects/component-project-1
projects/component-project-2
projects/webproject
          /app/bower_components/
```

run bower-auto-link on projects directory. It will identify the dependent modules for webproject and execute all commands to link.